# Google Cloud Function Accessing BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a google cloud function that accesses my bigquery data. However, I get an error when I run it. It works correctly if I run under the local emulator, but not when deployed.

My package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^0.9.6"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
var BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

exports.hello = function hello(req, res) {

    var bigQuery = BigQuery({ projectId: 'influence-ranking' });
    bigQuery.query({
        query: 'SELECT label from `influence-ranking.wikidata.labels` LIMIT 1',
        useLegacySql: false
    }).then(function () {
        return res.status(200).send('hello');
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    });
};
```

I deploy the function:

```
$ gcloud beta functions deploy hello --stage-bucket influence-ranking-web --trigger-http --project influence-ranking

Copying file:///tmp/tmpwR3Sza/fun.zip [Content-Type=application/zip]...
/ [1 files][  7.3 KiB/  7.3 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/7.3 KiB.                                      
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...done.                                                                      
availableMemoryMb: 256
entryPoint: hello
httpsTrigger:
  url: https://us-central1-influence-ranking.cloudfunctions.net/hello
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
latestOperation: operations/aW5mbHVlbmNlLXJhbmtpbmcvdXMtY2VudHJhbDEvaGVsbG8vdHJoV1pjeWlnSkk
name: projects/influence-ranking/locations/us-central1/functions/hello
serviceAccount: tfc7c97f9c5ac6052-tp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
sourceArchiveUrl: gs://influence-ranking-web/us-central1-hello-poucdhlbhptc.zip
status: READY
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2017-09-20T18:42:22Z'
versionId: '15'


$ curl https://us-central1-influence-ranking.cloudfunctions.net/hello
{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Access Not Configured. BigQuery API has not been used in project 283683622993 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com/overview?project=283683622993 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com/overview?project=283683622993"}],"message":"Access Not Configured. BigQuery API has not been used in project 283683622993 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com/overview?project=283683622993 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."}
```

The link in the error message gives the error:

```
The API "bigquery.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it
```

It looks like the project parameter doesn't correspond to the project number listed for my project in google cloud console. So it makes me think that somehow I'm getting the request being made against the wrong project, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 6):

Something was messed up in my google cloud functions account.

I ended up:

1. Deleting all my functions
2. Disabling the google cloud functions
3. Re-enabling the google cloud functions

And now it works.

Importantly, the output from deploying now says:

```
serviceAccount: influence-ranking@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

So it is using the correct service account.

Comment: You didn't have to manually configure the service account, right? I'm trying to figure out how Cloud Functions and BigQuery works together without setting up the service account. Seems that Google does this automatically, as long as 2 things are under the same GCP project

Comment: @HoangTrinh, sorry can't recall in any detail how this worked two years ago.